# HTML iframe , Page is not loaded in iframe , but replaces whole webpage .

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to load , http://www.flipkart.com , in a frame .
But when it loads , my webpage is replaced with , flipkart home page.

To clarify  , window.location.href is changed to flipkart.com  .

Can I track this event of redirecting means , like can I open a dialog box  - saying 
1. Stay on this page .
2. Leave this page .

Answer (score 1):

Nope, sites have this as a prevention from loading them in an iframe (short of asking your users to disable javascript)

Answer (score 1):

**flipkart iframe hack trick**

you can force flipkart to stay within iframe using sandbox attribute (with allow forms).
however there are some limitations like js wont work.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

Flipkart uses below code in there HTML to prevent any frame loading their site.

```
function noxfs() {
    try {
        if (window.top !== window.self) {
            document.write = "";
            window.top.location = window.self.location;
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.body.innerHTML = '';
            }, 0);
            window.self.onload = function() {
                document.body.innerHTML = '';
            };
        }
    } catch (err) {
    }
}
noxfs();
```

Here they update the window.top.location with their own location.
Their attempt to do can be intercepted and you can prevent come out of frame, by using below code.

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Any message here.';
};
```

Here you event handler which get fired before the window removes the DOM of existing page.